# Ошибка с тегом фрагмент, не принимает key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hook, react-router-dom

Где нужно указать ключ, чтобы ушла данная ошибка, нужно ли вообще использовать тег fragment, если можно использовать вот такие кавычки  <>  </> и обойтись без данного тега, понимаю, так, что он нужен, чтобы не добавлять лишних тегов.

Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";



const Columns2 = () => [
  <Fragment>
    <td key="1231312">data 1</td>
    <td key="2321312132">data 2</td>
  </Fragment>,
];

function Fragmentfun() {
  return (
    <table key='14'>
      <tbody key='13'>
        <tr key='12'>

          <Columns2 key='11' />
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}

export default Fragmentfun;
```

Comment: Какой версией React-a пользуетесь? И вы точно уверены, что ошибка в показанном куске кода? Вставьте ваш код как воспроизводимый React код, чтобы мы увидкли ошибку. Вот инструкция как это сделать https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/how-do-i-create-a-react-stack-snippet-with-jsx-support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конкретно в вашем примере для того, чтобы избавиться от сообщения об ошибке, нужно добавить `key` лишь для корневого узла (в нашем случае это фрагмент) компонента `Columns2`. Однако для того, чтобы фрагмент мог получить `key` подобно пропсу он должен быть обозначен в JSX разметке в полной форме, вот в таком виде:

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";


const SomeComponent = () => {
  /** укажите здесь любой key на ваш выбор, можно даже использовать значение из пропсов */
  return (
   <Fragment key={"anyKey"}>
    ...
  </Fragment>
 ),
};
```

Ниже представил ваш пример, но только с необходимыми `key`, чтобы избавиться от сообщения об ошибке

```js
const {Fragment} = React;

const Columns2 = () => [
  <Fragment key="1">
    <td>data 1</td>
    <td>data 2</td>
  </Fragment>
];

function Fragmentfun() {
  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <Columns2 />
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Fragmentfun />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```